# Calling subroutines in different Fortran modules

Tags: fortran

I have been developing a free code for computational thermodynamics in the new Fortran standard for the last 10 years it it works quite well but it is large, more than 60000 lines of code and some 500 subroutines.  The software calculates equilibria, phase diagrams and simulates phase transformations using model parameters read from
assessed databases.

Recently I was asked to provide an encrypted database with this
software and I agreed to try to do that.  The actual encryption is
done by an independent vendor which will also provide a library with routines to decrypt the database.  However, I am obliged to prevent anyone extracting the database parameters from inside my software so I have to provide a small pre-compiled library together with the decryption library to store and calculate with the decrypted model parameters in a way that prevents a programmer to extract the model parameters from my software.

This task required a major reorganizing of my data structures and to extract some subroutines in a special library which will not be part of the free software.  I have managed to modify the data structure and I have extracted a small set of subroutines for the calculations with the decrypted parameters.  However, when reading the model parameters from the encrypted database I must find a place to store these related to the elements and phases selected by the user.  The subroutines to find this place are in the program I want to keep free and develop.  So while reading the encrypted database in the library module I must access a large number of subroutines in the free software.

I will try to explain my problem in a simple way using figure 1 where a main program calls subroutine SUBB inside module MODA.  SUBB calls SUBC which calls SUBC before returning.  This is the way my original code works and it is no problem because all subroutines are inside the same module.

figure 1

```
module moda
contains
  subroutine suba(ib)
    integer :: ib
    write(*,*)'suba 1:',ib
    ib=5
    call subc(ib)
    write(*,*)'suba 2:',ib
  end subroutine suba
!
  subroutine subb(id)
    integer :: id
    write(*,*)'subb 1:',id
    call suba(id)
    write(*,*)'subb 2:',id
  end subroutine subb
!
  subroutine subc(ie)
    integer :: ie
    write(*,*)'subc 1:',ie
    ie=2 
    write(*,*)'subc 2:',ie
  end subroutine subc
end module moda

program main
  use moda
  integer if
  if=0
  call subb(if)
  write(*,*)'Value: ',if
end program main
```

Assume SUBA is the subroutine reading the encrypted database and
storing the model parameters in a secret way.  I have made this into a separate module (and library) in figure 2 which will not be part of the free software.  The library will be compiled independently of the main program.

figure 2

```
module secret
!  use modb, only: subc   creates compilation error
contains
  subroutine suba(ib)
    integer ib
    ib=5
    call subc(ib)
  end subroutine suba
end module secret
```

In figure 3 I separated out the module MODB (as I tried to "use" that for SUBA) and in figure 4 the main program.

Figure 3

```
module modb
!  use secret, only: suba   creates compilation error
contains
  subroutine subb(id)
    integer :: id
    call suba(id)
  end subroutine subb
  subroutine subc(ie)
    integer :: ie
    ie=2
  end subroutine subc
end module modb
```

Figure 4

```
program main
  use modb
  use secret
  integer if
  if=0
  call subb(ie)
  write(*,*)'Value: ',if
end program main
```

All my attempts to link this together fails, either by compilation
errors when I "use" the different modules or that "SUBC_" is an
undefined reference.  I have spent a few weeks to handle the data structure problems, I thought the subroutine calls would be easier. Any hint is welcome.

I understand that "use" between two modules is probably illegal and anyway problematic but I have no idea how to handle this.  I can not make the whole of MODB module part of the SECRET module because I want to keep it as small as possible.  The code is still developing and I cannot maintain separate parts.

But maybe there is an elegant solution.  I understood this "only:"
trying to solve this problem.  Maybe there is some "interface" or
"external" feature I do not know about.

For development I use gfortran, gcc 10.2.0 from MSYS2 on Windows but my software is used on various Linux machines and MacOS.  The current version is available on sundmanbo/opencalphad repository on github.

Answer (score 4):

Your `secret` module depends on module `modb` which depends on objects from the `secret` module. That is a circular dependency. It can be readily resolved via Fortran 2008 `submodule`s. The essence of the idea is to separate the interfaces of module procedures from their implementation. You would have to put the interfaces in the module in one file and the implementations in a `submodule` in a separate file. To avoid the compilation errors, you would have to then compile the module files (containing the interfaces) first, followed by the implementations (build generators like CMake would automatically detect the dependencies and do this for you). Here is an example implementation,

Contents of `secret_mod.F90`:

```
module secret

    implicit none

    interface
        module subroutine suba(ib)
            integer, intent(out) :: ib
        end subroutine
    end interface

end module secret
```

Contents of `secret_mod@Routines_smod.F90`:

```
submodule (secret) Routines_smod

contains

    module procedure suba
        use modb, only: subc
        ib = 5
        call subc(ib)
    end procedure

end submodule Routines_smod
```

Contents of `modb_mod.F90`:

```
module modb

    implicit none

    interface

        module subroutine subb(id)
            integer, intent(out) :: id
        end subroutine

        module subroutine subc(ie)
            integer, intent(out) :: ie
        end subroutine

    end interface

end module modb
```

Contents of `modb_mod@Routines_smod.F90`:

```
submodule (modb) Routines_smod

contains

    module procedure subc
        ie = 2
    end procedure subc

    module procedure subb
        use secret, only: suba
        call suba(id)
    end procedure subb

end submodule Routines_smod
```

The key is have the dependencies only in the submodules (not in the modules). Now compile while respecting the module/submodule order,

```sh
gfortran secret_mod.F90 modb_mod.F90 secret_mod@Routines_smod.F90 modb_mod@Routines_smod.F90 main.F90 -O
./a.out
 Value:            0
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick anser, I will test and maybe have some more questions.  submodules are now for me.

Comment: See also the chapter on submodules in "Modern Fortran Explained: Incorporating Fortran 2018" by Michael Metcalf et al. It has a very good summary of the submodule features.

Comment: The problem is to ask the right question to get a relevant answer.  Just reading text books or manuals I found a waste of time.  I have Arjen Markus book which is nice but there is no section (or even index) refering to modules or submodules.

Comment: As I have understood the submodule feature was added to avoid copying large parts of code into different modules to simplify calls.  However, I find some features such as "private" and "public" are not allowed in submodules which forces a lot of modifications of existing code.  If I had known about submodules earlier and been aware of the need to separate out some parts to handle encrypted databases this could probably been handled easily but modifying several 100 subroutines in different modules is not easy.

Comment: Any private or public object in the parent module is visible to the child submodule(s). But any definition in the submodule is automatically only visible to the submodule and its child submodules. Do not put any declarations or type definitions in the submodule if they have to be accessible from outside the module (definitions should all appear in module)

Comment: I have also read some more comments about modules/submodules and there is obviously no standard for .mod or .smod files and they may even change for different versions of the compiler.  I am beginning to doubt it is possible to separate out the part of the code that should be secret.  Maybe I should provide a stand alone version of the software without source code for using encrypted databases

Comment: That is true. The only way is to compile the source with different compilers and possibly different versions, and distribute all. The latter is seldom needed though.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you can resolve your circular dependency using a [submodule](https://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Submodules). Submodules allow you to separate the procedure interfaces from the procedure implementations.

In your code, only the implmentation of `suba` needs to know about `subc`. So by separating `suba` into a module and a submodule, this moves the dependency on `modb` from the module to the submodule.

Using a submodule, your code would look like

```
module secret
  interface
    module subroutine suba(ib)
      integer ib
    end subroutine suba
  end interface
end module secret

submodule (secret) secret_submodule
  use modb, only: subc
contains
  subroutine suba(ib)
    integer ib
    ib=5
    call subc(ib)
  end subroutine suba
end submodule

module modb
  use secret, only: suba
contains
  subroutine subb(id)
    integer :: id
    call suba(id)
  end subroutine subb
  subroutine subc(ie)
    integer :: ie
    ie=2
  end subroutine subc
end module modb

program main
  use modb
  use secret

  integer if
  if=0
  call subb(ie)
  write(*,*)'Value: ',if
end program main
```